# how can i clear the configurationmanager cache for connectionstrings

Tags: .net, runtime, configurationmanager, connection-string

I am trying to change the database name in the connectionstring located in the App.Config of our servicehost at runtime and restart it afterwards connecting to another database. This works fine, but only if the application is shut down for multiple seconds. Shutting down the application for several seconds seems  to clear the cache of the ConfigurationManager.Connectionstrings. The problem is that due to this required shutdown time, I can not use Application.Restart() in my application.

The strange thing about this caching behaviour is that even when the value is updated in memory (in the example the second time it is requested) the updated value is displayed correctly. But when the application is restarted the old value seems to re-emerge.

To verify the behaviour create a new console app.

add an App.Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DomainDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=InitialDBName;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

then add the following code to the Main method

```
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
        DbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
        Configuration appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        builder.ConnectionString = appConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DomainDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        //print initial value
        Console.WriteLine("initial " + (string)builder["Initial Catalog"]);

        //change value
        builder["Initial Catalog"] = "ChangedDatabaseName";
        appConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Remove("DomainDBConnectionString");
        appConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings("DomainDBConnectionString", builder.ConnectionString));
        appConfig.ConnectionStrings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
        appConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

        Console.ReadLine();

        DbConnectionStringBuilder builder2 = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
        Configuration appConfig2 = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        builder2.ConnectionString = appConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DomainDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        Console.WriteLine("changed " + (string)builder2["Initial Catalog"]);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

To reproduce this behaviour, you need to run the application (by hitting F5) and close it.
afterwards the solutionname.exe.config file will show up with the modified value.
If you run the application a second time (**this time by doubleclicking the solutionname.exe**) you will notice the difference in behaviour if you do this immediately after terminating your application, or after you have waited a couple of seconds.

In my opinion the configsection should be re-read because of 
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
but apparenatelly this does not work as advertised.

Comment: To the guy who edited my tags. This has nothing to do with ASP.Net. My servicehost is a console application.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's still .net - the risk of not tagging questions properly is that other people will tag it for you, and they'll get it wrong :)

Answer (score 9):

2 Things:

First when you are in debug mode you are not using `solutionname.exe.config`; you are actually using `solutionname.vshost.exe.config` so thats why your inconsistent behavior because the `solutionname.vshost.exe.config` file goes back to the original version as soon as you stop the application; loosing any changes you made to it.

Seconds this line of code `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");`
 not always works as expected. I have found that some times is better to refresh parent section or section group; in this case would be "configuration".

so try `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("configuration");`

Comment: ConfigurationManage.RefreshSection("configuration") did not help for me... I worked around this by using Application.Restart() after saving changes to Configuration (P.S. Note that Application.Restart() has to be called from Program.Main() otherwise after restart application will be started in 2 instances)

Comment: I have verified that it's unfortunately impossible to run RefreshSection on "configuration".

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to reside in the fact that the first time, I run the application from visual studio (with debugger enabled).

If I run the application from the bin/debug directory the caching problem does not seem to exist.

For my production environment this will fix my problem (so in other words my problem is fixed). This however does not kill my curiousness of the cause of the difference in behaviour.